# Display Results in ListView from Database

Tags: android, listview, android-sqlite

I am trying to display result from Database in a listView which is clickable On long click ,items can be deleted and on click it go to another activity. So I create an activity called editdeletedoctor

```
public class editdeletedoctor extends Activity {
    private ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
    private String tableName = TableData.TableInfo.TABLE_DOCTOR;
    private SQLiteDatabase newDB;
    private ArrayList<doctorClass> doctor_List = new ArrayList<doctorClass>();
    public static String MODEL_TO_EDIT = "MODEL_TO_EDIT";
    public ListView list;
    public ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);
        init();
        openAndQueryDatabase();
        displayResultList();
    }

    private void init() {
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(editdeletedoctor.this,
                        registerdoctor.class);
                intent.putExtra("theText", doctor_List.get(position).getUsername());
                intent.putExtra(editdeletedoctor.MODEL_TO_EDIT,doctor_List.get(position));
                editdeletedoctor.this.finish();
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        list.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    final int position, long id) {
                Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(editdeletedoctor.this);

                dialog.setTitle("Are you sure you want to delete This doctor?");

                dialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        doctorClass doctor = doctor_List.get(position);
                        doctor_List.remove(position);

                        DatabaseOperations db = new DatabaseOperations(getApplicationContext());
                        try {

                            db.open();
                            HashMap<String, String> conditionKV = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            conditionKV.put(TableData.TableInfo.DOCTOR_ID, doctor.getId() + "");
                            
                            db.deleteDoctor(conditionKV);
                            results.remove(position);
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        } catch (SQLiteException se) {
                            Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(),
                                    "Could not create or Open the database");
                        } finally {
                            if (db != null)
                                db.close();

                        }

                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

                dialog.setNegativeButton("No", new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

                dialog.show();
                return false;
            }
        });

    }

    private void displayResultList() {

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, results);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        list.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    }

    private void openAndQueryDatabase() {
        DatabaseOperations db = new DatabaseOperations(getApplicationContext());
        try {

            db.open();
            doctor_List = db.getDoctor(null);
            for (doctorClass inc : doctor_List) {
                if(inc.getId()==TableData.TableInfo.userID)
                results.add("Name: " + inc.getUsername() + " Phone:"
                        + inc.getPhone() + ",Address: "
                        + inc.getAddress());
            }
        } catch (SQLiteException se) {
            Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(),
                    "Could not create or Open the database");
        } finally {
            if (db != null)
                db.close();

        }
    }

}


And in the DatabaseOperations.java class :

    

    public DatabaseOperations open() throws SQLException {
            ourHelper = new DatabaseOperations(context);
            ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            return this;
        }
        public void close() {
            ourHelper.close();
        }
        public ArrayList<doctorClass> getDoctor(HashMap<String, String> conditionKV) {
            Cursor m_cursor = get(TableData.TableInfo.TABLE_DOCTOR, conditionKV);
            ArrayList<doctorClass> list = new ArrayList<doctorClass>();
            if (m_cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    doctorClass model = new doctorClass();
                    if (m_cursor.getString(m_cursor.getColumnIndex(TableData.TableInfo.DOCTOR_ID)) != null)
                        model.setId(m_cursor.getInt(m_cursor.getColumnIndex(TableData.TableInfo.DOCTOR_ID)));
                    if (m_cursor.getString(m_cursor.getColumnIndex(TableData.TableInfo.DOCTOR_NAME)) != null)
                        model.setUsername(m_cursor.getString(m_cursor
                                .getColumnIndex(TableData.TableInfo.DOCTOR_NAME)));
                    if (m_cursor.getString(m_cursor.getColumnIndex(TableData.TableInfo.DOCTOR_PASS)) != null)
                        model.setPassword(m_cursor.getString(m_cursor
                                .getColumnIndex(TableData.TableInfo.DOCTOR_PASS)));
                    if (m_cursor.getString(m_cursor.getColumnIndex(TableData.TableInfo.DOCTOR_MAIL)) != null)
                        model.setEmail(m_cursor.getString(m_cursor
                                .getColumnIndex(TableData.TableInfo.DOCTOR_MAIL)));
                    if (m_cursor.getString(m_cursor.getColumnIndex(TableData.TableInfo.DOCTOR_PHONE)) != null)
                        model.setPhone(m_cursor.getString(m_cursor
                                .getColumnIndex(TableData.TableInfo.DOCTOR_PHONE)));
                    if (m_cursor.getString(m_cursor.getColumnIndex(TableData.TableInfo.DOCTOR_ADDRESS)) != null)
                        model.setAddress(m_cursor.getString(m_cursor
                                .getColumnIndex(TableData.TableInfo.DOCTOR_ADDRESS)));
                    if (m_cursor.getString(m_cursor.getColumnIndex(TableData.TableInfo.DOCTOR_GENDER)) != null)
                        model.setGender(m_cursor.getString(m_cursor
                                .getColumnIndex(TableData.TableInfo.DOCTOR_GENDER)));
                    list.add(model);
                } while (m_cursor.moveToNext());
            }// end if
            return list;
        }
        public Cursor get(String tableName, HashMap<String, String> conditionKV) {
            String whereClause = null;
            if (conditionKV != null)
                whereClause = formatWherecondition(conditionKV);
            String completeQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + tableName + " ";
            if (whereClause != null) {
                completeQuery += " WHERE " + whereClause;
            }
            return ourDatabase.rawQuery(completeQuery, null);
        }
        
        public String formatWherecondition(HashMap<String, String> conditionKV) {
            try {
                String result = "";
                if (conditionKV.size() < 1) {
                    throw new Exception("Hahsmap condition Empty");
                }
                Iterator l_iterator = conditionKV.keySet().iterator();
                boolean isOneField = false;
                while (l_iterator.hasNext()) {
                    String l_key = (String) l_iterator.next();
                    String l_value = conditionKV.get(l_key);
                    if (isOneField)
                        result = result + " AND ";
                    result = result + l_key + "='" + l_value + "' ";
                    isOneField = true;
                }
                return result;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }
        
        public void deleteDoctor(HashMap<String, String> conditionKV) {
            delete(TableData.TableInfo.TABLE_DOCTOR, conditionKV);
        }
        
        private void delete(String tableName, HashMap<String, String> conditionKV) {
            String whereClause = null;
            if (conditionKV == null)
                return;
            whereClause = formatWherecondition(conditionKV);
            String completeQuery = "DELETE FROM " + tableName + " ";
            if (whereClause != null) {
                completeQuery += " WHERE " + whereClause;
                ourDatabase.execSQL(completeQuery);
            }
        }
```

When running, an error occured, [Here is the logcat](http://i62.tinypic.com/ix8h2w.png)

Please help me .

Thank you

Comment: Please note that the problem is in the openAndQueryDatabase() method

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the "context" you are using here is not null ?
How about rewriting the `open()` function this way and calling it via `open(getApplicationContext());` ?

```
 public DatabaseOperations open(Context context) throws SQLException {
                ourHelper = new DatabaseOperations(context);
                ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                return this;
            }
```

Comment: Could you please filter the Stacktrace only for your app or scroll a bit down 
Furthermore the problem of the NPE is actually solved as far as I can tell from your output. You have another kind of exception now.

Comment: Could you repost your recent changes ?

Comment: this exception is showed after trying your solution and removing it, so that the code stills the same ,, the problem is in the openAndQueryDatabase() method since when I commented it no error occured .. hope you can help me

Comment: The only sure way you can find any error on your own is by using Log statements and tracking the execution flow. This method is useful especially when you don't wanna use the debugger..